# Http Service error in Angular2

Tags: angular, module

I'm making some tries with angular2 http module.

Here is an angular component that make a GET request:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'fountain-app',
  providers: [Http],
  template: require('./main.jade')
})
export class MainComponent {

  public constructor(
    private $http: Http
    ) {
    //
  }

  public getImage(): void {
    this.$http.get('https://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2015/11/26/121631321-63ff8328-4925-4ee2-9ff5-a81974b7074e.jpg')
    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(image => this.image = image);
  }
}
```

And here is the main module declaration (note the httpModule import):

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {UIView, UIRouterModule} from 'ui-router-ng2';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MainComponent} from './main';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header';
import {TitleComponent} from './title';
import {FooterComponent} from './footer';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UIRouterModule.forRoot({states: STATES, configClass: MyUIRouterConfig}),
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    TitleComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [UIView]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For some reason when I start the call I get this error:
**EXCEPTION: Error in ./MainComponent class MainComponent - inline template:0:93 caused by: backend.createConnection is not a function**

I don't know why I'm getting this and

P.S. I know that Angular2 was used to use HTTP_PROVIDER and then deprecated it in order to push HttpModule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't add `Http` in your providers array in `@Component` :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fountain-app',
  template: require('./main.jade')
})
```

`Http` it's already provided by `HttpModule`.

in fact `Http` has many dependencies so if you want to provide your own Http service you have to provide those dependencies.

Comment: you are welcome don't forget to mark my answer as correct ;)